# Why I am getting wrong neighbors from the graph

Tags: r, graph, igraph, neighbours

I am trying to find the common neighbor of a node from a graph. But, I am getting `the wrong neighbor` for `node 8`. From the dataset, we can say the common neighbor for the `node 8` are `node 5 and 6` but I am getting `node 4 and 5`!

Code:

```
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df_graph, directed = FALSE)
plot(graph, vertex.label = V(graph)$name)
neighbors(graph, 8, mode="all")
```

Output:

```
+ 3/8 vertices, named, from a32ba25:
[1] 4 5 8
```

Graph:

[image]

Could you tell me why I am getting the wrong neighbor?

Reproducible Data:

```
structure(list(To = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
8L), From = c(7L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to make the distinction between vertex names and vertex indexes. If you use a numeric value, that indicates you are using vertex indexes. Depending on the order of your data when you create the graph, then index may not be the same as the name. If you run

```
V(graph)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 8 7 6
```

That shows you the names of the vertices in index order. So the 8th vertex is actually vertex "6". If you want to get the neighbors for the vertex with the name "8", then you a character value.

```
neighbors(graph, "8", mode="all")
# [1] 5 6
```

This might have been more clear had you not used numbers for vertex names. In your data.frame, your to and from values can be any character values you like. The graph will just assign them an index in the order in which they are encountered. If you want the vertices to be in a specific order. You can set that order with the `vertices=` parameter

```
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df_graph, directed = FALSE, vertices=data.frame(name=1:8))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So, if I want to use the `1, 2, 3` in my dataset then, what I have to change after loading the `dataframe`?

Comment: You don't have to change your data, you just need to use those values as names so they must be inside quotes. If you want to set a specific vertex order, you can use the `vertices=` parameter of `graph_from_data_frame` (see updated answer). But index values always start at 1 and go up by one. You can't have any missing or skipped values if you want the vertex index and name to be the same. That's why it's better to stick with names in general.

Comment: Thank you. We are using `1:8` because I have only `8 vertices`. So, if I have 20 then I have to write `1:20`? Node names mean, like 'Node_1, Node_2 and anything instead of 1, 2, and integer`?

Comment: By names I just mean using `"1"` and `"2"` rather than `1` and `2`. Characters/string values are interpreted as names, numeric values are treated as indexes.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, is there any way to see all neighbors of all nodes (at a time) instead of one by one?

Comment: If you have some time, please check this question, I will grateful (stackoverflow.com/questions/66826023/…)